# how to display data received from android client in server.js to html file?

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I wrote this node.js server which receives data from android client .But i tried to display the data in html page i could not display and i don't have any idea how to display in html page since am a beginner in nodejs. I just started to explore to get count of active users in realtime.

my nodejs server.js code

```js
var net = require('net');
var sockets = [];
var connectCounter=0;
var svr = net.createServer()
svr.on("connection",function(sock) {
    connectCounter++;
  var remoteAddress = sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort;
  console.log("new client connection is made %s", remoteAddress);

    sockets.push(sock);

    sock.write('Welcome to the server!\n');
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Data from %s :%s", remoteAddress, data);
        sock.write("Hello", + data);
        console.log("connection_id:", + sock.id);
        console.log("Number of active state(connection) :",connectCounter);
      
      });
    sock.on('end', function() {
        connectCounter--;
        console.log('Disconnected: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
        console.log("Number of active state(disconnected) :",connectCounter);
        var idx = sockets.indexOf(sock);
        if (idx != -1) {
            delete sockets[idx];
        }
    });
});

var svraddr = 'localhost';
var svrport = 3000;

svr.listen(svrport, svraddr);
console.log('Server Created at ' + svraddr + ':' + svrport + '\n');
```

My android code

```
socket = new Client("localhost", 3000);
socket.setClientCallback(new Client.ClientCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onMessage(String message) {
               System.out.println("Socket_connection_msg" + message);
           }

           @Override
           public void onConnect(Socket sockett) {
               try {
               JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
               jsonObject.put("name" ,"MainActivity");
                   jsonObject.put("value" ,"45");
                   socket.send(jsonObject.toString());

               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               System.out.println("Socket_connection" + sockett.isConnected());
               //socket.disconnect();


           }

           @Override
           public void onDisconnect(Socket socket, String message) {
               System.out.println("Socket_connection_disconnect" + socket.isConnected()+ message);
           }

           @Override
           public void onConnectError(Socket socket, String message) {
               System.out.println("Socket_connection_error" + message);
           }
       });
       socket.connect();
```

My console output is

When a new android device is connected active state increases and if user goes out of app it disconnects and connection gets decremented by 1.
[image: my output]

Now i need the response to displayed in HTML page

I am new to nodejs , any help would be appreciated

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `But i tried to display the data in html page` ??? You want to put that data in a html page maybe? And who should display the html page? Please edit your post and explain better what should happen.

Comment: `Thank you in advance.` That is not very inviting.

Comment: `socket = new Client("localhost", 3000);` What is `socket` ? If you use `localhost` then the android app assumes that the server runs on the same Android device as the client is running.

Comment: i use my ip adress for post i have replaced with localhost and i don't know how to send data to html page, it was just a try but nothing resulted so i did not post my html page

Comment: You have not answered my questions. So i do not know what you want to happen. Just tell your scenario step by step. Put all in your post. Make a decent story to begin with. It's so unclear now. So the client sends some data to the server. Ok. Then what does the server do with the data? Further: Is the server sending back something? If yes then what? Put all in your post. Make a decent story.

Comment: sever doesn't send any data to client when client got connected it just send the welcome message. Sever only receives the connection count and disconnect count. how to push connect and disconnect count to html page

Comment: It is pretty unclear wher there is a html page. And who would look at that html page? Where is a browser that requests that html page? Or what should happen? You are still not telling what should happen.